# Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Matter is not defined

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I am using matter.js and p5.js but I seem to get this error when I debug sketch.js. Both files are in their correct location and correctly referenced but Matter still seems to be undefined.

**Index.html**

```
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>p5.js example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #1b1b1b;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="../matter.js"></script>
  <script src="../p5.js"></script>
  <script src="../addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
  
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**sketch.js**

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    //Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Composite = Matter.Composite;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  var engine = Engine.create();
  var world = engine.world;
  var box1 = Bodies.rectangle(200, 100, 80, 80);
  Engine.run(engine);
}

function draw() {
  background(51); // sets background color
  rect(box1.position.x, box1.position.y, 80, 80);

}
```

Comment: What does your dev tools network tab? Are all the scripts loading properly?

Comment: Your Js files are not being mapped correctly. Check the location or just put all in the same  directory to load them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the required javascript files are not being recognised. I have reproduced your example using cdn of the libraries you actually wanted to use.

**sketch.js**

```js
let Engine = Matter.Engine,
    //Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Composite = Matter.Composite;
let world;
let box1;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    let engine = Engine.create();
    world = engine.world;
    box1 = Bodies.rectangle(200, 100, 80, 80);
    Engine.run(engine);
}

function draw() {
    background(51); // sets background color
    rect(box1.position.x, box1.position.y, 80, 80);
}
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>p5.js example</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #1b1b1b;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.5.0/lib/p5.js"></script>"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <main>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, also as a follow up question, when I add World.add(world, box1); under Engine.run(engine); the box and background seem to disappear when I run the code.

Comment: Check console for the error in the browser.

Comment: The error is still Matter is not defined. The code you  provided allowed the box to show on the screen but the error message hasn't changed